# Can not find class DoubleSummaryStatistics

Tags: java, android, import

forgive me but I'm a beginner. I need your help.
When trying to build my application I have this error, as you can see on the screenshot and I do not know how to solve it.
[The screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iaPxQ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java 8 added summary statistics.  We can calculate all statistical information such as count, min, max, sum, and average in one go. Java 8 provides DoubleSummaryStatistics for double data type, IntSummaryStatistics for integer data type and LongSummaryStatistics for long data type. These classes work with stream of elements.

**So we need to set target vesion is 1.8 of JDK/JRE in android studio**

Like

```
android {
  ...
  defaultConfig {
    ...
    jackOptions {
      enabled true
    }
  }
  compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, I made the changes, but now I have this error: Error:(13, 0) Could not find method jackoptions() for arguments [build_8p3fjuhjrqkjacy9y2tkmoq1f$_run_closure1$_closure3$_closure8@6fb12d] on ProductFlavor_Decorated{name=main, dimension=null, minSdkVersion=DefaultApiVersion{mApiLevel=15, mCodename='null'}, targetSdkVersion=DefaultApiVersion{mApiLevel=23, mCodename='null'}, renderscriptTargetApi=null, renderscriptSupportModeEnabled=null, renderscriptSupportModeBlasEnabled=null, renderscriptNdkModeEnabled=null, ...

Comment: Hello; I used the code above and now i have this: Error:(4, 0) Cause: startup failed:
build file 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\projectfolder\app\build.gradle': 4: unexpected token: ... @ line 4, column 3.
     ...
     ^

1 error

Answer (score 0):

The documentation of [`DoubleSummaryStatistics`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/DoubleSummaryStatistics.html) says:

> Since:
>   1.8

The configuration of how to enable Java 8 on Android is on [Google Developers offical guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/platform/j8-jack.html#configuration). You just have to enable [jack compiler](https://source.android.com/source/jack.html)